# Column of keys on keyboard stop working

Tags: laptop, keyboard

My <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, and <kbd>.</kbd> randonmly stop working sometimes.

When it first started to happen I was able to fix it by disconnecting and reconnecting the keyboard's ribbon cable that attaches to the motherboard. This fix used to last a few days but now it does not work at all.

I haven't spilled anything on my laptop but this problem is common side effect of liquid damage. The keyboard is soldered into the laptop so a replacement would be a bit pricey, so I'd thought I would ask before spending the money. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try a USB Keyboard and see if all the keys work. Likely they will but do try.

Then assuming a USB Keyboard works, your laptop keyboard or ribbon cable is defective.

You said " was able to fix it by disconnecting and reconnecting the keyboard's ribbon cable"

That means the cable is being flexed and under some normal strain attaching or detaching the cable. Constantly doing may have worn out the cable (broken a conductor inside the cable).

Then it becomes up to you whether to repair or not.

Comment: You state, you tried, "disconnecting and reconnecting the keyboard's ribbon cable that attaches to the motherboard." If there is a ribbon cable, it is unlikely the keyboard is soldered into the case. Download a shop manual for your laptop -- replacement is usually *quite* easy (I just replaced one in an HP laptop held in place by a single screw and tabs on the edge!).

Answer (score 0):

The exact same keys stopped working on my old laptop and now the one im currently using is experiencing the same issue. Two different laptops made by different companies so rather this is some grand global conspiracy or a huge design flaw.

(not an answer, I know, but I thought it might be worth mentioning)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1165633)